# PHP to Python dict array variable and API substitution

Tags: python, php, arrays, api, email

I'm working on a Python script that sends emails. It is related to the API of one of the systems. I need to replace the Array in PHP with Python and put it in the 'to [vars]' field, but it doesn't work.

Below is the array that I have to rewrite from PHP into Python

```
'to' => Array(
    'mail_1@domain' => Array(
        'vars' => Array(
            'var1' => 'Value of var1',
            'var2' => 'Value of var2',
        ),
        'message_id' => 'own_message_id@domain'
    ),
    'mail_2@domain' => Array(
        'vars' => Array(
            'var1' => 'Value of var1',
            'var2' => 'Value of var2',
        ),
    'message_id' => 'own_message_id@domain'
    )
)
```

is an example where I should substitute:

```
data = {
'to[vars]' : '',
'smtp_account' : '1.account.smtp',
'subject' : 'Test template 2',
'html' : 'Some HTML',
'text' : 'Some Text',
}
```

here's an example of how I substitute

```
data = { 
 'to[mail_1@domain : vars : = {'var1':'Value of var1'}]' : '',
 'smtp_account' : '1.account.smtp',
 'subject' : 'Test template 2',
 'html' : 'Some HTML',
 'text' : 'Some Text',
}
```

In the API, the field is described as follows: to[vars] optional    String[] An array of variables for substitution in a template.

I also include a link to the documentation: http://dev.emaillabs.io/#api-Blacklist-blacklist_tmp_check

if anyone had an idea how to help I would be very grateful

Comment: Python equivalent will look like [this](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyWxJFHBVqGaSwEIlErylaygbDA/NzEzJ97QISUfyMhDkQJLlyUWFWOIwmQMgTJKYYk5pakK@WkKYAEdrAqN0BUaKaGoq0XVppSbWlycmJ4an5kC0phfnhePEIE5lQuLZohvjIa0b7ggZO3//wA).

Comment: Why don't you use JSON which is available and the same in any language?

Comment: The API declares in what form I need to insert the variables. Can this be done using JSON in each case?